# Determining Boundaries of Integral when Calculating CDF

Tags: probability, integration

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with mutual PDF
>
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^2y^2} & x\geq 1, \ y\geq 1\\ 0
> > &\text{else}\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
>
> Define
>
> $$U:=\frac{X}{Y} \quad V:=XY \tag{2}$$
>
> Compute the CDF $F_U$ for the random variable $U$.

For $u\leq 0$ we have $F(u)=0$

For $u>1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
F(u) = P[U \leq u] = P[X/Y \leq u] &= P[X \leq Yu] \\
&=\int_1^\infty \int_1^{yu}\frac{1}{x^2y^2}dxdy\\
&= \dots \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2u}
\end{align}$$

For $0 < u \leq 1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
F(u) = P[U \leq u] = P[X/Y \leq u] &= P[X \leq Yu] \\
&=\int_{1/u}^\infty \int_1^{yu}\frac{1}{x^2y^2}dxdy\\
&= \dots \\
&= \frac{u}{2}
\end{align}$$

Now I see that we have three cases, the first is basically just the definition of a CDF. The second and third reflect the fact that $U:=\frac{X}{Y}$ can be growing or falling.

But I do have trouble getting the lower bound of the $dy$ integral (i.e. $1/u$) for the case $0<u\leq 1$. How do I formally derive that?

Edit: I wanted to add: In hinsight I do understand the solution but I seem to have trouble deriving that for myself. So it might be beneficial to see the approach of someone else on deriving the boundaries. :)

Comment: Note that $f(x,y) \neq 0$ for $x \geq 1$ and $y \geq 1$. Now, in case $0 < u \leq 1$ you pick the integral for $Y$ to have lower limit $1/u$, to guarantee $yu \geq 1$ in the inner integral.

Comment: Okay, I think I got you. Can I basically explain it like this: The inner integral is clear. We further now that we have, as you said, $x\geq 1 \ y\geq 1$ and we further know that we have the relatioship $U=X/Y$, we turn that relationship into the upper bound of the inner integral and get $yu=x\geq 1 \ \Rightarrow yu\geq 1$ resp. $1\leq yu \ \Rightarrow 1/u\leq y < \infty$

Comment: Yes, so the inner integral is from 1 to $yu$ but only if $yu \geq 1$ and therefore $y \geq 1/u$.